# numpy roots negative exponential function

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have read [numpy.roots](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.roots.html), which works out common algebraic function's y axis intersections.

which

```
y = ax^n + bx^{n - 1} + cx^{n - 2} ...
```

and exponentials are always natural number.

so by passing in

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

I am basically working out

```
y = x^2 + 2x + 3
```

but I need to bring in negative exponentials, such as

```
y = x^2 + 2x + 3 - x^{-1}
```

I wonder if I can construct a dict, for the instance above

```py
{2: 1, 1: 2, 0: 3, -1: 1}
```

which **keys are exponentials and values are coefficients**, and work out the roots.

---

any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: You could multiply the polynomial by the lowest power of `x`, e.g. `x^2 + 2x + 3 - x^{-1} -> x^3 + 2x^2 + 3x - 1`.  This should preserve the old roots, and possibly add a new root at zero (which you can discard).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you got a "polynomial" with negative exponents, it is not really a
polynomial but a fractional function, so to find the roots you can simply find the roots of the numerator polynomial.

In a function

[image]

you can factor out the last term

[image]

which is equal to

[image]

So we can say

[image]

The function g(x) is a polynomial of `n+m` degree and finding the roots of g(x) you'll get the roots of f(x) because the denominator cannot be zero (x=0 is outside the domain of f(x), when it's zero you get a singularity, in this case a division by zero which is impossible).

## EDIT

We can graphically verify. For example, let's take a function with these coefficients

```py
import numpy as np
coeffs = [1, 6, -6, -64, -27, 90]
roots = np.roots(coeffs)
roots

array([-5.,  3., -3., -2.,  1.])
```

As you can see we got 5 real roots.

Let's now define a polynomial with the given coefficients and a fractional function

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def print_func(func, func_name):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, .5))
    ax.set_xticks([])
    ax.set_yticks([])
    ax.axis('off')
    ax.text(0, .5, 
            f"{func_name}\n"
            fr"${func}$",
            fontsize=15,
            va='center'
           )
    plt.show()

def polynom(x, coeffs):
    res = 0
    terms = []
    for t, c in enumerate(coeffs[::-1]):
        res += c * x**t
        terms.append(f"{c:+} x^{{{t}}}")
    func = "".join(terms[::-1])
    print_func(func, "polynomial")
    return res

def fract(x, coeffs, min_exp):
    res = 0
    terms = []
    for t, c in enumerate(coeffs[::-1]):
        e = t + min_exp
        res += c * x**e
        terms.append(f"{c:+} x^{{{e}}}")
    func = "".join(terms[::-1])
    print_func(func, "fractional")
    return res

x = np.linspace(-6, 4, 100)
```

So this is the polynomial

```py
y1 = polynom(x, coeffs)
```

[image]

and this is the fractional function

```py
y2 = fract(x, coeffs, -2)
```

[image]

Let's plot them both and the found roots

```py
plt.plot(x, y1, label='polynomial')
plt.plot(x, y2, label='fractional')
plt.axhline(0, color='k', ls='--', lw=1)
plt.plot(roots, np.repeat(0, roots.size), 'o', label='roots')
plt.ylim(-100, 100)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

You see they've got the same roots.

Please note that, if you had a fractional like

```py
y2 = fract(x, coeffs, -3)
```

[image]

i.e where the denominator has an odd exponent, you could think there is a root in x=0 too, simply looking at the plot

[image]

but that's not a root, that's a singularity, a vertical asymptote to ±∞. With an even exponent denominator the singularity will go to +∞.